# Proper way of binding a dictionary to a cshtml table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My story is: I'm working in a asp.net MVC project. I have two Model's list, reprezented like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<string, string>>> _foldersName_NoRecords = new Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<string, string>>>();
private List<string> _totalNoOfDates = new List<string>();
```

after I fill those lists(as I've seen after debug the fill goes perfectly), I pass them to a ViewBag for accessing them in the view. The problem is that the lists are not displayed in the order they are filled in and are rather overridden.
The code from the view is:

```
 <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Folder Name
                    @foreach(var  date in @ViewBag.dateList)
                    {
                         <td>@date</td>
                    }
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach(var tupleKey in @ViewBag.statisticsList.Keys)
            {
                <tr>
                   <td> @tupleKey </td>
                    @foreach (var tupleItem in @ViewBag.statisticsList[tupleKey])
                    {
                        foreach (var date in @ViewBag.dateList)
                        {

                                if (tupleItem.Item1 == date)
                                {
                                    <td>@tupleItem.Item2</td>
                                }

                        }
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
```

for example: `@tupleItem.Item2` is not displayed to the date that it belongs when a new key is added(the data stored from the lists is extracted from txt files).  Anyone have any idea of better displaying this data?

Comment: The ordering goes perfectlly when debuging C# code, but in the view the ordering is problematic(the data is overridden).

Comment: What output is generated now? What do you want it to be instead?

Comment: for example at date "12.07.2017" I don't have a certain value for a certain key. The non-value is overridden with the next value(which belongs to the next date). So, "12.07.2017" has a value for that key.. which is  not OK

Answer (score 0):

Since Tuple has many overloaded options, why not have a third `DateTime` parameter that you can use to link the contents of the Tuple to the contents of the date?  If you want to keep the lists separate, ensure the ordering on loading the dictionary/list is the same; sounds like something is getting out of order.

Comment: Date is represented as a string, as in Tuple and also in dateList(I don t think that I need the third parameter). The ordering goes perfectlly when debuging C# code, but in the view the ordering is problematic